# Rails - getting errors installing the spreadsheet gem using rubygems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to be able to deal with excel spreadhseets in rails.
So I am using the `spreadsheet` library.
However, when I use rubygems to install the spreadsheet, I get an exception:

```
Successfully installed spreadsheet-0.7.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for spreadsheet-0.7.1...
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/internals.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader/biff8.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/biff8.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/format.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/n_worksheet.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/workbook.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/worksheet.rb, skipping
Installing RDoc documentation for spreadsheet-0.7.1...
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/internals.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader/biff8.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/biff8.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/format.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/n_worksheet.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/workbook.rb, skipping
unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK
for lib/spreadsheet/excel/writer/worksheet.rb, skipping`
```

then in my doSomethingController, i wrote the code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
```

but the server returns the error

```
cannot load such file -- spreadsheet
```

can you help me figure out what has happened and how can i fix the exception

My environments:

```
ruby 1.9.3
rubygem 1.8.16
```

Comment: what version of Rails are you running?  You can ignore these exceptions, they only occur when you are installing the Rdoc documentation files, the `spreadsheet` gem is still installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your gems:

```
gem list
```

Check for that one being installed:

```
gem list | grep spreadsheet
```

Follow the instructions for use at http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet which also talks about Development Dependencies:

```
hoe ~> 2.13   
rdoc ~> 3.10
```

There is a great "getting started" guide at http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/files/GUIDE_txt.html

The wiki - http://spreadsheet.ch/ is also useful.

Comment: thank you for your help,i follow your advise,install the hoe ~>2.13 rdoc ~>3.10 spreadsheet ~>0.7.1 and check my gems that the spreadsheet has been installed by gem,but the exception still exist,i think maybe the exception is about the gem not spreadsheet,my rubygem can't unable to convert "\xE2" to UTF-8 in conversion from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 to GBK

Comment: hi i don't know why i can't load the spreadsheet lib in my project,when i create a new project then load the lib everything goes well.thank you.