# Ruby roo LoadError: cannot load such file -- spreadsheet/note

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Try load xls file and get this error. There is console log:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'roo'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> a = Roo::Excel.new('/home/a.xls')
LoadError: cannot load such file -- spreadsheet/note
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.2/lib/spreadsheet/excel/reader.rb:5:in     `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/spreadsheet-0.9.2/lib/spreadsheet.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/roo-1.12.2/lib/roo/excel.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Please help fix this problem

Also when I try require spreadsheet I get the same error

```
require 'spreadsheet'
```

But this module was install

```
$ gem list | grep spreadsheet
spreadsheet (0.9.2)
```

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969144/rails-getting-errors-installing-the-spreadsheet-gem-using-rubygems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to fix version of "spreadsheet" gem to "0.9.0".

In my case adding

```
gem "spreadsheet", "0.9.0"
```

right before roo gem made a trick.

Comment: Thanks, it's realy help! :)